# Why is the wrong address saved in API file input/output?

Tags: io

Situation:

1. Using API dialog. When you left-click the mouse, a dialog is created, where you decide on the value to be saved to the file, and when you press the 'OK' button, it is saved to the binary file. And the dialog closes.
2. After the dialog box closes, right-click to read the saved file.

Problem: I have no problem reading the file as soon as it is first created. However, in OpenFile(), the following error appears after the function is completed.

> Exception occurred (0x00403CEC, example.exe): 0xC0000005: An access violation occurred while reading location 0x0081F674.
> An unhandled exception was thrown: Read access violation.
> **_Pnext** was 0x5A1CE4.

I know that that error occurs when you try to access a memory area that you don't have permission to access. Why does this problem occur? The code is below.

```
typedef struct
{
    int ID_Name;
    int ID_Emotiation;
    string str;
}CCharacter_Script;

void myDebugMsg(const char* format, ...)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    char str[128];
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vsprintf(str, format, args);
    OutputDebugString(str);
    va_end(args);
#endif
}

void Save(int nameID, int emotationID, char script[])
{
    CCharacter_Script character;
    character.ID_Name = nameID;
    character.ID_Emotiation = emotationID;
    character.str = script;

    FILE* fp, * op;

    fp = fopen("Save_Script.bin", "rb");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fp = fopen("Save_Script.bin", "wb");
        fwrite(&character, sizeof(CCharacter_Script), 1, fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
    {
        fclose(fp);

        op = fopen("Save_Script.bin", "ab");
        fwrite(&character, sizeof(CCharacter_Script), 1, op);
        fclose(op);
    }
}

void OpenFile()
{
    CCharacter_Script character;
    FILE* fp;
    int r_count;

    fp = fopen("Save_Script.bin", "rb");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        OutputDebugString("Error :: None File\n");
    }
    else
    {
        OutputDebugString("Reading :: Script\n");
        // Continue repeating until you reach the end of the file
        while ((r_count = fread(&character, sizeof(CCharacter_Script), 1, fp)) > 0)
        {
            myDebugMsg("Name: %d    Emotation: %d\n '%s'\n", character.ID_Name, character.ID_Emotiation, character.str.c_str());
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the 'save()' function, you are trying to open the file in 'append binary mode' for writing, but you are using the pointer 'fp' instead of 'op' after closing the initial file pointer.

try this save() function instead

```
void Save(int nameID, int emotationID, char script[])
{
CCharacter_Script character;
character.ID_Name = nameID;
character.ID_Emotiation = emotationID;
character.str = script;

FILE* fp, * op;

fp = fopen("Save_Script.bin", "rb");

if (fp == NULL)
{
    fp = fopen("Save_Script.bin", "wb");
    fwrite(&character, sizeof(CCharacter_Script), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
else
{
    fclose(fp);

    op = fopen("Save_Script.bin", "ab");
    fwrite(&character, sizeof(CCharacter_Script), 1, op); // Use 'op' instead of 'fp'
    fclose(op);
}
}
```

Comment: I made changes as you said. But still the same error occurs...

Comment: It might be the way you're handling the string within the CCharacter_Script structure.  The string class handles dynamic memory allocation internally, and directly writing the structure to a file might not give expected results.  Try changing the str member in the CCharacter_Script struct to a fixed-size char array to ensure it's directly writable to the file and use strcpy() to copy the script string into the str member of the CCharacter_Script struct.

Comment: Certainly, there is no problem if you change it to a char array. However, the reason I used string was because I thought it would be more efficient in terms of memory storage. Is there any way to use it as a string? Or is it actually more inefficient in terms of memory to use it as a string?

Comment: Using 'std:string' is more convenient and safer (in terms of memory and avoiding buffer overflow issues). However, directly writing such objects into binary files can cause complications. This is because of the internal structure of 'std:string'. When you write the object into file using 'fwrite', you are basically writing memory address of string's internal buffer and not the characters itself. So, when you read them back, you will get memory addresses and not the string. To properly read and write to and from a file, you need to serialize and deserialize.